# Why does a walkie talkie have TS for audio output and TRS for audio input?

Tags: audio, stereo

Why does a walkie talkie have TS for audio output and TRS for audio input?

Is there any sense to have stereo for microphone and mono for speaker?

Why doesn't the manufacturer use TS for both audio input/output?

Please see walkie talkie audio jacks that I have:

[image: Walkie talkie audio jacks]

Comment: What brand and model walkie talkie do you have?

Comment: does the mic have PTT (push to talk)?

Comment: Yes, mic has PTT.

Comment: I have Midland GXT1000. Most Midland walkie talkies have the same audio jacks. @JRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a stereo microphone. One of the pins is for the push-to-talk button, and the other is the microphone. The speaker doesn't have a button, so it doesn't need an extra pin.